# Suppose a and b are real numbers such that $ab^{2}=1$ and $a^{3}+3b^{3}=4$. What is the product of all possible values of $a^{3}+b^{3}$?

Tags: contest-math

2019 MathCon Finals Grade 11 Part C

I've been struggling with this one for quite a while, and I couldn't find any answers on the internet. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: From the two given equations, you can eliminate one variable and get an equation for the other alone. For example, eliminating $a$ you get $0=3b^9-4b^6+1=(b-1)(b^2+b+1)(3b^6-b^3-1)$. The vanishing of the factor $b^2+b+1$ doesn't produce real solutions. The factor $b-1$ gives $b=1$. We could compute the real solutions of $3b^6-b^3-1$, but we will only need $b^3$ which is one of the values $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}{6}$. Since $a^3+b^3=(b^{-3})^2+b^3$. put there $b^3$ equal those values and multiply.

Comment: @NDB Sorry to trouble you again. [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) says comments are not for answering a question. In case you do not agree with that established rule, please raise a question on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's rearrange the first equation for $a$.
$$ab^2=1$$
$$a=\frac{1}{b^2}$$
Substituting this into the second equation,
$$a^3+3b^3=4$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{b^2}\right)^3+3b^3=4$$
Let's let $x=b^3$. We can rewrite the previous equation as
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+3x=4$$
$$1+3x^3=4x^2$$
$$3x^3-4x^2+1=0$$
You can now find the solutions to this equation. We can easily see that $x=1$ is a solution, so we can reduce this to a quadratic with polynomial long division.
$$\left(x-1\right)\left(3x^2-x-1\right)=0$$
Using the quadratic formula, we find the solutions to be
$$x=1,\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{6},\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{6}$$
The final part is to find the product of the possible values of $a^3+b^3$. Since $a=\frac{1}{b^2}$, this can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{b^6}+b^3$$
Substituting $x$ from before, this is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+x$$
However, this can also be rewritten as $(4-3x)+x=4-2x$ from an earlier identity. This means that the product will be equal to
$$(4-2x_1)(4-2x_2)(4-2x_3)$$
Substituting the three solutions into this expression leaves you with the final answer.

Comment: +1, though, I'd suggest, instead of calculating the roots of $3x^3-4x^2+1$, we can observe that $\left(4-2 x_1\right) \left(4-2 x_2\right) \left(4-2
   x_3\right)=-32\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)+16
   \left(x_1 x_2+x_3 x_2+x_1 x_3\right)-8 x_1 x_2 x_3 +64$ and use Vieta's formulas.

Comment: @Ennar, its simpler, as $\prod (a^3+b^3) = \prod (4-2b^3)=8\prod (2-x_i) = \dfrac83(3\cdot2^3-4\cdot2^2+1)=24$

Comment: @Macavity, indeed it is :)